# SIGABRT when trying to throw an exception

Tags: c++, exception, virtual-functions

I have a very strange problem, which took already several hours of my attention:

With giving a wrong input to the software I am working on, I can produce an exception (which is of course intended). This works fine and I see a correct error message when executing the program.
But when I pass the exact same input over the API (which yields to nearly the same control flow), the program crashes. With debugging I see the following (I use gdb for debugging):

- The Exception class (in this case called UserExcption and this class has no virtual methods and also its predecessors don't have any virtual methods) gets successfully instantiated.
- When I step "into the throw statement" (want to say that I just continue to step after the exception object is instantiated) I get the following output:

> (gdb) s
>
> pure virtual method called
>
> Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
>
> 0x00007fff95c64ce2 in __pthread_kill ()
>
> (gdb)

I really do not understand what happens here. Since now virtual methods at all are involved (as far as I see), I also cannot imagine, that there are some dangling pointers or something like this (otherwise I would expect to get a null pointer exception). Since the whole program is quite big and I don't have any idea where to look for the problem I also cannot reproduce it.

Does anyone have an idea what the source of such a behavior could be?

Best Markus

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1jgXhSmlUcGWf-ZsfM18LDOScBEc4IWIUKrozY2BS1xM - both stacks (before the throw statement and after are included)

Comment: do you have virtual calls in `zorba::UDFunctionCallIteratorState::~UDFunctionCallIteratorState`?

Comment: or dangling pointers of instance `UDFunctionCallIteratorState`

Comment: check the local variables inside try block of `zorba::http_client::general_evaluate` function.

Comment: did not find anything unusual - but as suggested by sergio I tried a clean build and this somehow solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you are calling some (not pure) virtual method from either a constructor or destructor, or possibly some cast going wrong. You should check this in your exception class, I guess, since you get the error while throwing one instance of it.

Indeed, the compiler will prevent you from having a class with a not implemented pure virtual function. On the other side, virtual function polymorphism is not entirely safe in constructor and destructors.

Just a suggestion, but without seeing the code, this is just an hypothesis.

I would also make a clean build, maybe you have some stale objects for some reason.

Comment: I now made a clean build and this solved the problem!! I don't understand this - is this a bug somewhere? (like our build system, cmake or even the compiler/linker). Do you have any idead how this can happen? Anyway: thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: I think it is related to some compiler/linker optimizations going the wrong way. It should not happen at all, in principle; though it happens.